# I want to write a program that calculates the sum and average of student grades

Tags: c#

Having problem with my work i want to write a program that does the sum and average the student grade in the average function i used a do while loop since i want anyone to enter grade until the user enter -1 the loop end.

The problem is i do not want to run the _cal = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); in the fucntion instead run it in the main by passing a value to Average() parameter then using the value in main as a console.readlIne because i will use the user input to divide by the sum in order to get average am new to programming.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the scores of your student: ");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
        _studentTotalGrade = Average();
        Console.WriteLine("sum " + Sum);



        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static double Average()
    {
        double _cal,_sumTotal = 0;
        int i = 0;

        do
        {
             _cal = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (_cal == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (_cal > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adjust score\");
                continue;
            }
            _sumTotal +=_cal;
            i--;
        } while (_cal > i);
        return _sumTotal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Average is: `total score/ number of students`. You're almost there. You have the total, just keep track of number of students so change `i--` to `i++` and return `_sumTotal/i`. Give your variables meaningful names so change `i` to `numberOfStudents`. And `Sum = Average();` doesn't make sense either because sum and average are different things.

Comment: Also you may want to place this inside the loop: `Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the scores of your student: ");` but change the wording to `Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the scores of your student between 0 and 20. Enter -1 if no more enteries. ");`

Comment: Since `-1` in your application means no more students to enter then change this `while (_cal > i);` to `while (_cal != -1);` meaning keep looping unless `-1` was entered. But you also have this condition `if (_cal == -1)` so upon entering `-1` you will jump out of the loop so, although your application will work, `while (_cal != -1);` will not be used in that case. So think about that too. Programming is more about thinking than coding :)

Comment: Hi i understand you say i should return _sumTotal/i it get me the average but, also is their a way i can use my              _cal = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 inside the main by passing variable to the average function parameter then using the variable in main for the user input. Am new and trying to understand while loop and function well because forloop is not for me.

Comment: You will get negative 4 if you're entering negatives for score or you didn't change `i--` to `i++`. Perhaps do not allow negatives to be entered by the user. Just take your time. You will figure it out. Use the debugger and if you don't know how, go on YouTube and search "visual studio how to use debugger"